# Accessing Properties in object

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

```
<script>      
  var foo = {          
    name: 'kevin'        
  };

  document.write(foo.name);
  document.write(foo['name']);

  var cool = 'name';
  document.write(foo.cool);

  document.write(foo[cool]);      
</script>
```

1. Why does `foo.cool` returns me undefined where as `foo[cool] returns
   me kevin`.
2. How does cool actually refer to my name property in foo object.

Comment: Because the `[]` notation is used when the object property is an expression, like your variable `cool` (or contains characters that cannot be used with the `.` notation). If you use the `.` notation, the property cannot be the result of an expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A `cool` property is not defined on `foo`, so `foo.cool` is undefined. If you did `foo.name`, it would return `kevin`.
2. `cool` in `foo[cool]` is the one you defined in the line above it, so it is actually `foo['name']`, which is defined and has the value `kevin`.

Comment: But var cool = 'name' is a string variable. How come JS associates it with the foo object just calling in the [] notation.

Comment: @Kevin - It doesn't. You are accessing the property of `foo` that has the tag `name`, but are passing in the variable holding this value (namely, the variable `cool` holding the value `name`). `name` is what's associated.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the properties either...

- Literally by their name: `property.name`
- Indirectly by an *expression that evaluates to their name*: `property[expr]`.

Hence if the expression `cool` has value `'name'`, then `foo[cool]` is the same as `foo['name']` or `foo.name`.

The brackets also allow for...

1) more complex expressions like `foo["data_"+variable]` to easily access fields named like `data_something`,
2) property names that aren't simple identifiers, for example you could say `foo["I'm long!"]`.

I hope this explanation brightens things up for you.

Answer (score 1):

In var foo = { name: 'kevin'};  You store an object or a dictionary to that variable... which is now a key-value pair... so you can access the value of an object using the key...

since its a key value pair... you can't access it using '.' operator... because foo is not a class... type of foo will be a dictionary or object...

so, to access the value you need to use the [] paranthesis...