# Difference between object.prop and object["prop"]

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I used to believe that there is no difference between them but after seeing this piece of code, all my information about objects in Javascript failed.

```
var search = function(name) {
  for(var x in friends) {
    if(friends[x].firstName === name) {
      console.log(friends[x]);
      return friends[x];
    }
  }
};
```

This code works. But

```
var search = function(name) {
  for(var x in friends) {
    if(friends.x.firstName === name) {
      console.log(friends.x);
      return friends.x;
    }
  }
};
```

this doesn't.

Thanks for explaining.

Comment: `friends.x` is the same as `friends["x"]`, not `friends[x]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing Properties in object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086573/accessing-properties-in-object) and [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`friends.x` is not the same thing as `friends[x]`, it's the same thing as `friends['x']`.

When you use `friends[x]` the value `x` can be a variable (or any expression), but when you use `friends.x` the `x` is a literal name, it won't use the variable `x`.

Comment: But, how can I write it with '.'. Or can't I?

Comment: @MindlessRanger: You can only use the `.` notation with a known name. The only way to access properties dynamically using that notation is to create code dynamically, e.g. `eval('friends.' + x)`, but there is no good reason to do it that way.

Comment: Thanks, accepting as answer now.

Comment: @MindlessRanger: Another significant difference is that when using dot notation and a property name literal (`friends.x`), the property name is limited to the [rules for *IdentifierName*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6) (a limited set of characters, can't start with a digit, etc.); but when using brackets notation and a string (`friends["x"]`), the property name can be anything (even just a single space, `" "`).

Answer (score 0):

As @Guffa already explained, `friends.x and friends['x']` are the same, the difference in those approaches is that when you use [] this syntax you can use variables, `'property like this'`, or reserved words, this is good when you do not know exactly the property you will need.

Comment: Actually, as of ES5, you can already use reserved words with dot notation (you couldn't in ES3 and before, but that was changed in ES5, by changing [§11.2.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1) to use *IdentifierName* instead of *Identifier*).